# Eclipse PDT/Symfony2 Plug-in - Project Errors

Tags: eclipse, symfony, eclipse-pdt

Hi I have followed the installation instructions of the Symfony2 Plug-in along with PDT on Eclipse. However whenever I create a new Symfony project I get error marks in the project explorer on the "vendor" folder and about 300 errors, mostly related "DLTK Problem".

Any suggestions or ideas on how to solve this problem ?

Comment: What exactly are error messages you get?

Comment: Hi, most of them are "Missing method implementation" related to implement clause associated to several classes. Here is one example: `class DB2Driver implements Driver` in this case is missing the implementation of several methods declared by the **Driver** class:                                                   `Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - Missing method implementations: loadMetadataForClass, getAllClassNames, 
  isTransient, 
 - Missing method implementations: _constructDsn, 
 - Missing method implementations: _constructPdoDsn,`

Answer (score 0):

the "Missing method implementations" problem is fixed in the latest version of the plugin. There was a bug in the validator. It now detects missing method implementations correctly and will provide a quickfix to generate the methods.